# What are the dimensions for the apple dock icons?

Tags: macos, dock, java

I have figured out how to change the icon for my program that I made in java, but now the default icon goes and nothing is there, is it because of the incorrect dimensions? I currently have a 16x16 logo, is anyone able to help me with what the dimensions need to do in order for it to display correctly?

Additional Note: The icon is a .png file if that helps in any way.

Answer (score 2):

An app's Dock Tile Icon should be **1024 × 1024**.

For more information about customising your Dock Tile, see the documentation:

- [Mac Developer Library: Dock Tile Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/customizing_docktile/intro/dockintro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000986-CH1-TP1)

Keep in mind that implementation (software development) is off-topic here.

Comment: Whoa! That seems awfully big for such a little thing! haha

Comment: It's still coming up blank - even when it is 1024 x 1024 - bearing in mind that this is Java.

Comment: @Connor [Implementation is off-topic here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Try [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), providing full details of what you are trying, with code.

Comment: I already have tried to post on StackOverFlow, but it is telling me to wait 7 days?